# Hive FROM_UNIXTIME() with milliseconds

Tags: hive

I have seen enough posts where we divide by 1000 or cast to convert from Milliseconds epoch time to Timestamp. I would like to know how can we retain the Milliseconds piece too in the timestamp.

1440478800123   The last 3 bytes are milliseconds. How do i convert this to something like YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.sss

I need to capture the millisecond portion also in the converted timestamp

Thanks

Comment: I have looked at the documentation sir. it wont retain the millisecond after conversion. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a hive udf in java

```
package com.kishore.hiveudf;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFType;

@UDFType(stateful = true)
public class TimestampToDateUDF extends UDF {
    String dateFormatted;
    public String evaluate(long timestamp) {
        Date date = new Date(timestamp);
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMDDHHmmss:SSS");
        dateFormatted = formatter.format(date);
        return dateFormatted;
    }
}
```

export as TimestampToDateUDF.jar

```
hive> ADD JAR /home/kishore/TimestampToDate.jar; 
hive> create TEMPORARY FUNCTION toDate AS 'com.kishore.hiveudf.TimestampToDateUDF' ;
```

output

```
select * from tableA;                                                           
OK
1440753288123
Time taken: 0.071 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> select toDate(timestamp) from tableA;
OK
201508240144448:123
Time taken: 0.08 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
select cast(epoch_ms as timestamp)
```

actually works, because when casting to a timestamp (as opposed to using from_unixtime()), Hive seems to assume an int or bigint is milliseconds. A floating point type is treated as seconds. That is undocumented as far as I can see, and possibly a bug. I wanted a string which includes the timezone (which can be important - particularly if the server changes to summer/daylight savings time), and wanted to be explicit about the conversion in case the cast functionality changes. So this gives an ISO 8601 date (adjust format string as needed for another format)

```
select from_unixtime(
   floor(  epoch_ms / 1000   )
 , printf( 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.%03dZ',  epoch_ms % 1000  )
 )
```

Comment: When i try to cast , it throws me Null and when i use the other option the query fails trying to evaluvate the Printf statement in the from_unixtime