# Hive date cast chopping of milli seconds

Tags: hive, hiveql

Below date cast is not displaying milli seconds.

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("2017-07-31 23:48:25.957" , "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"));

2017-07-31 23:48:25
```

What is the way to get milli seconds?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32237365/hive-from-unixtime-with-milliseconds

Comment: Why aren't you treating it as a timestamp instead of a string in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this string is in ISO format, the casting can be done straightforward

```
hive> select cast("2017-07-31 23:48:25.957" as timestamp);
OK
2017-07-31 23:48:25.957
```

or

```
hive> select timestamp("2017-07-31 23:48:25.957");
OK
2017-07-31 23:48:25.957
```

Answer (score -1):

because unix_timestamp is based on seconds, it truncate milliseconds.

Instead, you can transform string to timestamp using date_format, which preserve milliseconds. And then from_utc_timestamp.

```
select from_utc_timestamp(date_format("2017-07-31 23:48:25.957",'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'),'UTC') as datetime
```

Comment: is date_fromat a valid inbuilt function in hive?

Comment: @TKHN Yes, you can find the function description from here
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

Comment: its giving me error invalid function date_format..I am using Hive 1.1.0

Comment: @TKHN well, it is available from above Hive 1.2.0.